# Wordpress: Tiny editor not storing data

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to save data from tiny editor in my theme option but it is not saving. Here is my full case

```
case 'tiny':

    $tinysettings = array(
        'editor_class' => 'theme_editor',
        'tinymce' => array(
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,link,unlink,anchor,|,blockquote',
            'theme_advanced_buttons2' => 'formatselect,forecolor,|,image,|,sub,sup',
            'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '',
            'theme_advanced_buttons4' => '',
            'width' => '450',
            'height' => '200',
        ),
    );

?>

    <div class="options_input options_textarea">
        <div class="options_desc"><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></div>
        <span class="labels"><label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label></span>

        <div class="tiny-editor">
            <?php wp_editor( '', $value['id'], $tinysettings ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
break;
```

Comment: Just noticed that it is storing data and displaying on the front end but not displaying into the editor.

Comment: i do not understand what happens here and what you desire

Comment: I am using Tiny editor in wordpress theme option by using wp_editor() function. After save options it is storing into database and reflect on the front end as well but not in Tiny editor itself.

Comment: what do youmean by "Frontend"? (tinymce editor should is frontend too)

Comment: In my template. Content added by timnymce editor is visible in template but not in the tinymce editor itself in theme option.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
<?php wp_editor( '', $value['id'], $tinysettings ); ?>
```

The first argument is the actual content of the editor, but you have it set to an empty string.
If you save the content in a variable named $content, then this will work:

```
<?php wp_editor( $content, $value['id'], $tinysettings ); ?>
```